# Чому не можна замінити слово "противник" словом "ворог"?

Tags: значення-слів, синоніми

При написанні алгоритму складання бойового наказу, я написав пункт:

**"Вказати дані про ворога"**

Через що пізніше отримав зауваження, що в військовій справі кажуть лише "противник", а не "ворог". Однак, мені так і не пояснили чому.

В СУМі знаходимо як і [перше](http://sum.in.ua/s/protyvnyk), так і [друге](http://sum.in.ua/s/VOROGh) слово, тим більше дивимося значення слова "противник":

> Вороже військо, ворожі збройні сили; ворог.

Також бачимо, що ці слова є [синонімами](http://sum.in.ua/s/VOROGh), а тому я не розумію чому коли ми говоримо про військову справу ми не можемо вживати як одне, так і інше слово. Чи існує якесь пояснення цьому?

А також ось [Статут внутрішньої служби](http://zakon.rada.gov.ua/cgi-bin/laws/main.cgi?nreg=548%2D14&p=1143970339900570) (слово противник вживається 6 раз, а ворог - 0).

Comment: Можливо у слові "ворог" є оцінка, а у слові "противник" її нема? Як, наприклад, у боксі - люди б'ються не через те, що у них є якісь претензії одне до одного. Потенційно і солдат може не вважати конкретного противника ворогом через свої індивідуальні релігійні, національні чи якісь інші погляди.

Comment: А хіба у такому випадку не вживатиметься слово "суперник"? Хоча це радше стосується боксу, а не військової справи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проаналізувавши тлумачення в СУМ-11, а також власні відчуття щодо цих слів, я особисто вважаю так:

- *Противник*/*супротивник*/*опонент* — той, з ким ми б'ємося. «Б'ємося» може бути як у буквальному сенсі, так і якесь змагання.
- *Ворог* — слово, що виражає крайній ступінь негативного ставлення до когось (антонім до *друг*) або крайній ступінь жорстокості бою (насмерть).

Очевидно, що *ворог* — це не те слово, що слід було би вживати щодо спортивного змагання, хоча щодо війни воно в багатьох випадках може підходити. Однак навіть у військовій справі:

- Не кожен *противник* є *ворогом*. Теоретично статися так, що військовослужбовцям доведеться давати відсіч атаці з країни, яка в принципі не є ворогом. Наприклад, сталося якесь непорозуміння (дипломатичне — та країна піддалася на якусь провокацію, або військове — випадковий дружній вогонь через недоладну організацію сумісних дій союзників), але, поки дипломати чи командири це вирішують, задачею певної групи військовослужбовців може бути зупинити це.
- Не кожен *ворог* є *противником*. Наприклад, якщо ворогами нашої країни є країни X, Y і Z, але на певній ділянці фронту наступ веде саме Y, то для групи військовослужбовців, що обороняють ту ділянку фронту, противником є саме Y (а не якісь абстрактні для них X і Z, яких вони, можливо, й в очі не бачили, якщо ті воюють з країнами-союзниками).

Ймовірно тому, щоб не ускладнювати все неактуальними стратегічними й емоційними нюансами, у військовій справі теж надають перевагу слову *противник*. Бо *противник* — це той, із ким ми зараз ведемо (або потенційно маємо вести) бій (а не той, кого ми найбільше не любимо, або хто є найбільшим кривдником нашої країни, абощо). Також, припускаю, перевагу слову *противник* можуть надавати ще й через миролюбний характер нашої воєнної доктрини (якщо я не помиляюся, навіть мета бойових дій офіційно формулювалася не як *знищити*, а як *знешкодити*, мовляв, якщо ми знищуємо, то це тому, що це єдиний практично можливий спосіб знешкодити, а не тому, що нашою метою є саме знищення — але можу помилятися в цьому).

<sub>Ще пов'язані слова, деякі з яких вказували в коментарях:</sub>

- <sub>*Суперник* — це той, хто змагається за ту саму винагороду, що й ми (тобто його шанси на успіх зменшують наші, і навпаки). Тобто це слово, по-перше, часто несе конотацію гри (тому не підходить для воєнних дій), по-друге, не обов'язково припускає прямої сутички чи прямого протиставлення. Наприклад, у перегонах усі учасники *суперники* одне одному, але, на мою думку, не можна назвати їх *противниками*, бо немає прямого протиставлення; а от у боксі боксера в протилежному куті рингу можна назвати і *суперником* (бо він змагається за той самий пояс), і *противником* (бо він б'ється з нами).</sub>
- <sub>*Конкурент* — це той, хто змагається за той самий ресурс. Тобто аналогічно до *суперник* це слово має на увазі конфлікт інтересів (з прямою сутичкою чи без), але на відміну від *суперник* воно зазвичай застосовується до прагматичних цілей, а не до ігор.</sub>